# Shared Preferences removing data after one time use

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using Power Preferences in an android application because of storing a list of data in the key-value format and has been working great for me

Recently have added two other simple key-value pairs one is for the UUID of the device and the second for a custom generated id

there are no issues with the UUID as it is stored once on the first time using the app and retrieved many times
but with the custom generated id I can store it and use it perfectly only one, on the second time retrieving the key-value pair is removed for some reason generating a new id every alternate time

code for setting the power preferences

```
String deviceDBID = data.getDevicedbid();
PowerPreference.getFileByName(powerPrefFile).putString(powerPrefDeviceDBID, deviceDBID);
```

code for retrieving the power preferences

```
String deviceID = PowerPreference.getFileByName(powerPrefFile).getString(powerPrefDeviceDBID);
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps try to use `PowerPreference.showDebugScreen();` to check out the values stored in the preferences? Or try writing to a new filename.

Comment: It proves my doubts on what is happening and a great debug tool too. But the reason why it is happening I am not sure of because the only code I am using is to store and retrieve

Comment: One tip I can offer is besides writing to the PowerPerference, why not write to SharedPreferences too. If both exhibit the same weird phenomenon, perhaps the source code is the culprit. If SharedPreferences is OK and PowerPreference is NO GOOD, then the library is the issue.

Comment: that can be will check with it. but power preference is useful for storing list and map